# Vlcj gives "taglib meta writer error" when setting metadata on video file

Tags: video

I am using [vlcj](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) to write some metadata to video files to create a video library which could be sorted by title, date, artist, etc.

When I am trying to save the metadata that I set to the file, the following error appears:

> [00007ff7043d8f48] taglib meta writer error: File test.mp4 can't be opened for tag writing

I have based my test in the test [`UpdateMetaTest.java`](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/99b0f7f1a97a085bbe27513eba6dc8014ede9081/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/meta/UpdateMetaTest.java) of the official repo at Github.

This is the code that I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a media player
    MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

    // Get the meta data and dump it out
    MediaMeta mediaMeta = factory.getMediaMeta(args[0], true);
    logger.info("Metadata:");
    logger.info(mediaMeta);
    logger.info(LibVlcVersion.getVersion());

    // Set the artist of the video if it is not set
    if (mediaMeta.getArtist() == null) {
        mediaMeta.setArtist("Unknown");
        mediaMeta.save();
    }

    mediaMeta.release();
    factory.release();
}
```

This is my program output:

> 2015-10-04 13:51:27 INFO  MetaTest:65 - Metadata:
>   2015-10-04 13:51:27 INFO  MetaTest:66 - DefaultMediaMeta[title=test.mp4,artist=null,genre=null,copyright=null,album=null,trackNumber=null,description=null,rating=null,date=null,setting=null,url=null,language=null,nowPlaying=null,publisher=null,encodedBy=null,artworkUrl=null,trackId=null,trackTotal=null,director=null,season=null,episode=null,showName=null,actors=null,length=0]
>   2015-10-04 13:51:27 INFO  MetaTest:67 - 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax)
>   [00007fbc3c3e3138] taglib meta writer error: File test.mp4 can't be opened for tag writing

My vlcj version is 3.9.0 and my Libvlc library is 2.2.1.